# What is the & in emacs key binding?

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

For example, yasnippet provides the command `yas-new-snippet`, which is bound to `C-c & C-n`. I don't understand what this means. It does not mean to press Ctrl-C, then Ctrl-n (this should be `C-c C-n`). It also does not mean to press Ctrl-C, then n. What's the correct way to type it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just type <kbd>C-c</kbd>, <kbd>&</kbd>, and <kbd>C-n</kbd>.